# Java opengl : gl cannot be resolved

Tags: opengl, processing

I am trying to use [Processing](http://www.processing.org) 2.2.1 but I got the following error:

> gl cannot be resolved or is not a field

Here is my code:

```
import javax.media.opengl.*;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.*;
GL gl;
GLU glu; 
public PVector unProject (float winX, float winY)
{
  GL gl=((PGraphicsOpenGL)g).gl;  
  GLU glu=((PGraphicsOpenGL)g).glu;
  ((PGraphicsOpenGL)g).beginGL();
  // ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 8(). Try to read some java book. Because you write something that doesn't look like java. First of all there is no class. Everithing (except imports) in java must be inside class declaration

Comment: try to build your class in [ideone](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ideone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dp47VIOQHMHH8gfYjoKwDA). This is quite good in checking the apple-orange type of problems when using a programming language. I feel sorry for you as people have been downvoting you, but your problem is a very silly one and fixing this should be a part of your learning curve :)

Comment: @talex [Processing](http://www.processing.org) is a DSL that compiles into Java so it is Java like in syntax but is simpler for beginners, the question could have been clearer on this and I have edited it to make that clear

Comment: @waranchanu I am not sure why you are trying to access the OpenGL objects directly, using Processing all the standard library functions should provide everything you need to do both 2D and 3D graphics

Comment: @RobV .... I want to make java code to be able to open text file which is 3D.  I also tried to import all openGL object but it still doesn't work. So how can I use the openGL?

Answer (score 0):

`PGraphicsOpenGL` [has no property `gl`](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/opengl/PGraphicsOpenGL.html), not locally and not inherited, so trying to grab it will always give you an error. Why did you think you could do this?

And with that said: don't try to access Java subsystem things like the `g` context. Just use Processing properly. If you need to do 3d drawing, use the [3d API](http://processingjs.org/reference) functions provided, to do whatever you need to do. There is nothing that you need to do that requires reaching into the Java subsystem. Especially since you're not guaranteed to *have* a Java subsystem. Processing interpreters don't have to implement the Java stack in the slightest to run Processing programs. The processing.org IDE does, but that doesn't mean your code will always run in that.